# Using dom4J enabling opening and closing tags of empty elements

Tags: xml, dom4j

I am using dom4J API for dynamically creating XML. I am able to do this, however I am getting one issue.

Considering this element:
    `<Name></Name>`

This element don't have any value.

I add code like this:

Element name = root.addElement("Name");

But in generated XML, the element gets generated like this:
    `<Name/>`
That is it doesn't add opening and closing tags for the elements which don't have any value.

I did lot of online search on this but not able to do this. Can anyone help me if there is any setting which directs dom4J to explicitly add opening and closing tags for elements (even if there is no value).

Any help in this would be of great help.

Comment: Why does it matter? With XML the meaning of `<Name></Name>` is the same as the meaning of `<Name/>` or <Name />`, all three are ways of marking up an empty `Name` element.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dom4j/io/XMLWriter.java#L155 is the constructor for an `XMLWriter` that takes an `OutputFormat` where you could set

```
outputFormat.setExpandEmptyElements(true);
```

see https://github.com/dom4j/dom4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/dom4j/io/OutputFormat.java#L271.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. Is there any way to specify the behaviour when we create the document object, as in: Document document = DocumentHelper.createDocument();